# How can i see the CPU temperature on the panel?

Tags: temperature, gnome-panel, 21.04

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04 and can't put application's icons on the panel for some reason. Is there any way of seeing the temperature without having a tab of an application open?

Comment: Something like [Freon](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/841/freon/) or [Sensors](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/82/cpu-temperature-indicator/) might give you what you're looking for ...

Comment: Tried to find those but couldn't in store, while searching i found Hardware Sensors Indicator instead. It works just fine, I'd recommend it to anyone.